Understanding the number/ structure of critical (non-maximal rank Jacobian) points for differentiable maps
Given a differentiable map $f:\mathbb{R}^{m} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and suppose $m < n$. I am interested in understanding how critical points, i.e., points where the jacobian has rank $< m$, can be characterized.
In particular, I understand there are cases where no critical points exist, others where a finite number of critical points exist. I recall reading somewhere that it's also possible for a continuum of critical points to exist along some low dimensional curve/ surface of the domain.
Beyond this, what possible structures can the set of critical points exhibit? What structures/ cardinalities are more 'frequent'? Is it possible for these sets to get very gnarly/ random? What if I assumed each component of f was convex, i.e., $f_{i}(\cdot): \mathbb{R}^{m} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a convex map for each $i \in \{1, 2, ..., n\}$. Does this provide any more structure than the general case?
I'd very much appreciate any thoughts, or if I could be pointed to resource(s) to understand this concept better. Just not sure where to look and I don't have a background in smooth manifolds/ differential geometry

Your terminology is wrong to begin with. What book are you reading? Also, you can realize any closed subset as (what you call) the set of critical points.

Thanks for your response. I'm not formally studying the subject, just stumbled upon a related problem during a discussion with a colleague, and neither of us are well versed in this area. A quick Google search took me to Wikipedia's page on Critical Points, and it's stated there that critical points are points where the rank of the jacobian matrix is not maximal. Could you point me to a better resource?

Any textbook on differential topology, say, Guillemin and Pollack.

You are dabbling in the field called singularity theory. You might check out Guillemin and Golubitsky.

An excellent book on singularities is the book by Arnold, Varchenko, Gusein Zade (t.1) where the structure of critical points is explained at the very beginning with many interesting examples. They start with map from $R^n\to R$ then $R^2\to R^2$, and define the more general Thom- Boardmann $\Sigma ^I$ symbols.
